# How to make auto type command in dosbox window using batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, dosbox

am new to Dosbox. I have downloaded Dosbox.exe from internet to play olden game dave.exe

What I did is,

- opened dos.exe
- typed `mount c c:\dave\`
- typed `c:`
- typed `dave.exe`
- after these dave game will open in dosbox.

**Note : c:\dave\ is the path of dave.exe game file**

My need is , How can I open that dave game without typing these commands ? I mean my idea is when I can able to create a batch file which run those mount command itself , I can play the game just by opening that batch file and no need o type that command line in dos bos. If it is cmd.exe I know to write commands. But, for dosbox.exe how to run a auto run command like batch or using batch ?

In simple words, I just want to play dave.exe game in single click using batch file.

for example : a batch file named dave.bat and it contains,

```
@echo off
cls
:DAVE
echo PRESS 1 - PLAY DAVE
echo.
set /p %opt%==1 goto PLAYDAVE
echo invalid option
goto DAVE
:PLAYDAVE
(here need auto execution and all mount command's to play dave using dosbox)
```

But, no idea what to do ! and what command Please help

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want this to run when DOSBox starts you probably have to add lines into "Autoexec.bat" (assuming Dosbox is like DOS, then this is loaded each time the DOSBox starts.)

Since you want it to ask you if it should load dave then it should happen at the END of "Autoexec.bat"

IE

```
REM Add these Lines to the AutoExec.bat file Below the existing
REM un-altered content in that file.
@echo off
cls
:DAVE
 echo. Please Choose an Option:
 echo.  1) PLAY DAVE
 echo.
 echo.  Any other value: Finish Loading DOSBox Normally
 echo.
 SET /P "_Choice=Please Enter a Choice (1,2,3,etc): "
 IF /I "_Choice" EQU "1" CALL :PlayDave
:ELSE
GOTO :EOF

:PlayDave
 Mount c c:\dave\
 CD /D c:
 CALL dave.exe
GOTO :EOF
```

If however, these are commands which are fed to doss-box to have it load a file on your actual computer system (and I suspect they are) then you would need to supply the image to be loaded as a command line argument like this:

```
DOSBox.exe "C:\Dave\Dave.exe"
```

Since I'm not 100% sure based off your wording I am trying to give you both answers, with the most likely one being this much simpler one.

So try the second option 1st.

Comment: one final thought, if you need to you could make the batch file an external choice to run DOSBox each with separate game parameters or you can have DOSBox load such a batch file by specifying it the way I do in the second part.  these are two ways of combining the two concepts put forth here whcih might be preferable depending on your needs.